# Does the unit test setUp/tearDown work in asynchronous testing?

Tags: unit-testing, dart

I was trying to work with it today in a scenario similar to this:

```
group('some group', (){
  //prints
  setUp(() => print('set up'));

  test('some test', (){
    window.requestLayoutFrame(
      expectAsync0((){
        Expect.isTrue(true);
      })
    );         
  });

  //doesn't print
  tearDown(() => print('tear down'));
});
```

In this example, the tearDown callback does not seem to be called.

When I place the tearDown() function before the unit test, then it does get called, but the output sequence is not what I would expect:

```
group('some group', (){
  setUp(() => print('set up'));

  tearDown(() => print('tear down'));

  test('some test', (){
    window.requestLayoutFrame(expectAsync0((){
        print('in unit test');
        Expect.isTrue(true);
    }));     
  });
});
```

Yields:

```
set up
tear down
in unit test
PASS: some group some test
```

Shouldn't the unit test output before the tear down?

SDK build 9881

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug. Resolved: http://www.dartbug.com/4284